# Is there a better way to grab a list of Avro records from an InputStream?

Tags: java, avro, bytearrayinputstream

I have a `ByteArrayInputStream` that was serialized with a `List<TestAvroModel>` which is an implementation of SpecificRecord. I could not find a way for Avro to know about the list that was serialized so I did a hackish way to loop through the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

---

```
//TestAvroModel is an implementation of SpecificRecord
List<TestAvroModel> models;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for(TestAvroModel model: models) {
    DatumWriter<SpecificRecord> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(model.getSchema());
    Encoder encoder = new EncoderFactory().binaryEncoder(byteArrayStream, null);

    writer.write(model, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
}
```

---

```
//This was pre-serialized with a List of TestAvroModel
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream;

DatumReader<TestAvroModel> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(TestAvroModel.getClassSchema());
Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory().get().binaryDecoder(inputStream, null);

List<TestAvroModel> records = new ArrayList<>();
boolean eof = false;
while(!eof) {
    try {
        records.add(reader.read(null, decoder));
    catch(EOFException ex) {
        eof = true;
    }
}
```

This way worked and read the serialized `List<TestAvroModel>` one at a time and added it to my records list. Though looping through a `DatumReader` until an `EOFException` does not seem like the best way, but I haven't found a better way.

I couldn't find anything in the Avro libraries that dealt with an `InputStream` with multiple Avro records in it. Though it has to have breaking points in the stream for Avro to be able to read individual records the way I did above. To reiterate, does anyone know a better way to loop through the `DatumReader` then the way shown above?

Comment: I am curious how you serialized your data, can you share it with us? what about create a schema on the fly with a list of your records to handle this ?

Comment: @hlagos I have updated my question with a piece of the code on how I serialize my test data. Also I am confused with what you mean to create a schema on the fly for the list of records.

Answer (score 0):

`Decoder` seems to define `isEnd(): Boolean` for that purpose:

> Returns true if the current BinaryDecoder is at the end of its source
> data and cannot read any further without throwing an EOFException or
> other IOException.

This should work:

```
...
while(!decoder.isEnd()) {
  records.add(reader.read(null, decoder));
}
```